# Передача настроек для дальнейшего получения массива на одной странице jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

На странице имеется таблица.

Необходимо `чудом` отослать запрос, и поэтому запросу вывести таблицу с указанными в запросе данными.

Это всё организовать без перезагрузки страницы.

С Ajax'ом разобрался, но выходит туфта, когда я отправляю запрос, он возвращает мне уже готовую таблицу и вставляет её в нужный мне блок.

А суть такая, что я хочу отрисовать всю таблицу, именно через файл с которого и был запрос, а не вставлять готовую.

Суть вопроса:
   Отправить запрос в другой файл.
   В файле обработать данные.
   Вернуть массив PHP кодом, а не готовым HTML кодом.
   На странице от которой был послан запрос, обработать этот PHP код и вывести желаемое.

Comment: вопрос хрень полная.. проще забить на него и всё.
Но если найдётся человек который понял всё то дерьмо что я написал, благодарочка!

Comment: не видно вашего кода.

Comment: Насколько я понял, Вы немного не понимаете, как это работает. Есть сервер, который работает на php и есть клиент, который работает на html, js и т.д. Если Вы хотите получить после ajax-запроса данные, а не html-код, то страница, куда посылается запрос, должна возвращать данные. Но только вот получать эти данные будет клиент, и на клиентской стороне работать с php не получится. Но можно вернуть данные в понятном js формате и создавать таблицу средствами js

Comment: уже в процессе всё. Переделываю всё, чтобы послать запрос, вернуть все данные полученные с файла и всё пока что работает, осталось по мелочи сделать

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'];

echo json_encode($array);
```

?>

Оформляйте ваши данные в json и через js работайте с готовым массивом как в php)